# Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', xxxx) in SocketServer

Tags: python, sockets, http

I wrote a preview function based on SimpleHTTPServer and SocketServer, I catch `KeyboardInterrupt` exception as I enter `Ctrl-C` to stop server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import sys 
import SimpleHTTPServer 
import SocketServer

class Reuse_TCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    timeout = 1
    allow_reuse_address = True

def preview(port=8000):
    try:
        Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
        httpd = Reuse_TCPServer(("", port), Handler)
    except OSError as e:
        print("Could not listen on port {}".format(port))
        sys.exit(getattr(e, 'exitcode', 1))

    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit) as e:
        print("Shutting down server")
        httpd.socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    preview()
```

But most of the time , **if I open localhost:8000 and immediately(some seconds) enter 'Ctrl-C'**, it will display the message first and then close the socket:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2014 22:20:42] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2014 22:20:42] "GET /static/css/autumn.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
^C----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52787)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 310, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
----------------------------------------
f^C----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52788)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 310, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
----------------------------------------
^CShutting down server
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @laike9m sorry, I have update question: "how to solve this problem"

Comment: I still don't know what your problem is

Comment: You also have to press Ctrl-C multiple times for it to work?

Comment: @laike9m The problem is how to solve what I have paste in my quesion, the message "Exception happened during processing of request from...."

Comment: When I run your code, I get a clean shutdown: http://pastebin.com/J9224Ts5; I'm also on OS X and I used the OS X bundled Python 2.7.

Comment: @ErikAllik , If you open http://localhost:8000 and immediately enter 'Ctrl-C', will cause this problem.

Comment: That's something you should have mentioned in your question in the first place. Also, it would be freakingly hard to get the timing right because the responder contains nothing and thus takes too little time to respond.

Comment: @ErikAllik, yes, that's my mistake, I have update my quesion and strong the statement.

Comment: In any case, I don't see why this is a problem anyway... how often do you press Ctrl-C in production.. and who really cares if it shuts down beautifully or not.

Comment: @ErikAllik, wait some seconds(maybe 3s or more)，it still have this problem, I think some seconds is not a short time, and receive buf msg should not need so long.

Answer (score 4):

I'm experiencing exactly the same. I found an old bug in Python 2.7 and a patch that was supposed to solve this. I checked it and the patch is of course already in SocketServer.py. However, it didn't solve this problem.
In any case, the explanation in the link I'm pasting here is worth to be read to try to get a hint.

https://bugs.python.org/issue14574

Comment: same here: same problem, same frustration, same annoying exceptions clogging up my logfiles.